# Automatically parse some fields to string on mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I have an object that looks like this

```
{
  name: 'abc',
  value: BigNumber('125'),
  other: {
    otherValue: BigNumber('252'),
  }
}
```

Its mongoose schema is:

```
{
  name: { type: String, required: true },,
  value: { type: String, required: true },,
  other: {
    otherValue: { type: String, required: true },,
  }
}
```

Is there a way to automatically parse `value` and `otherValue` to string (by calling `.toString()`) before storing the object or the only way is to do it by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose allows a [`set`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-set) property, in your Schema, that will be used to alter the value before insertion.

You could use this `set` property to "stringify" your values.

```js
{
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  value: { type: String, required: true, set: (val) => val.toString()},
  other: {
    otherValue: { type: String, required: true, set: (val) => val.toString() },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried like this ?

```
{
  name: 'abc',
  value: BigNumber(125).toString(),
  other: {
    otherValue: BigNumber(252).toString(),
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  name: 'abc',
  value: BigInt(125).toString(),
  other: {
    otherValue: BigInt(252).toString(),
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  name: 'abc',
  value: 125n.toString(),
  other: {
    otherValue: 252n.toString(),
  }
}
```

Example result:
[image]